# Passing data between screens React Native. Data undefined

Tags: react-native, mobile

What I want is to open a recipe card, and then have the recipe instructions display on a different screen.

However, I keep getting an error which says that the "item" is undefined.

This is the recipe card. When it is clicked it should open up the new screen which displays the recipe instructions.

```
import {
  FlatList,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  Pressable,
} from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import { recipeList } from "../constants/constants";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";

const RecipeCard = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={recipeList}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Pressable
            onPress={() =>
              navigation.navigate("RecipeDetails", {
                screen: "RecipeDetails",
                params: { item: item },
              })
            }
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "#FDF7F1",
              marginTop: 25,
              borderRadius: 10,
              color: "white",
              paddingVertical: 20,
              paddingHorizontal: 20,
              borderRadius: 10,
              shadowColor: "black",
              shadowOffset: { width: 1, height: 4 },
              shadowOpacity: 0.1,
              shadowRadius: 4,
              alignItems: "center",
            }}
          >
            <Image
              source={item.image}
              style={{
                resizeMode: "center",
                width: 125,
                height: 150,
              }}
            />
            <Text style={{ bottom: 10 }}>{item.name}</Text>
          </Pressable>
        )}
        numColumns={2}
        columnWrapperStyle={{ justifyContent: "space-between" }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
export default RecipeCard;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

This is the recipe details. It should display the instructions of the recipe which should come from the data of the card that was clicked on. Here is where I am getting my error.

```
import { Pressable, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";

const RecipeDetails = (navigation, route) => {
  const { item } = route.params;

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Header />
      <Text>Hello I am the details screen</Text>
      <Pressable onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
        <Text>the icon</Text>
      </Pressable>
      <View>
        <image source={item.image} />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default RecipeDetails;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be `route.params.params` because you are sending param as a key. The passed data is stored in `route.params` so your `route.params` will be

```
{
    screen: "RecipeDetails",
    params: { item: item },
}
```

As you can see above, you don't have any `item` key here.

Try with below code

```
import { Pressable, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";

const RecipeDetails = (navigation, route) => {
  const { item } = route.params.params;//change here

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Header />
      <Text>Hello I am the details screen</Text>
      <Pressable onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
        <Text>the icon</Text>
      </Pressable>
      <View>
        <image source={item.image} />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default RecipeDetails;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried your solution, but it is still undefined.

Answer (score 0):

. You should update it to accept route and navigation as separate arguments as well you are taking image tag wrong , it starts with I (in capital) and you've taken it in small.

```
import { Pressable, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
    import React from "react";
    import Header from "../components/Header";
    import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
    
    const RecipeDetails = ({navigation, route}) => { 
      const { item } = route.params;
    
      return (
        <SafeAreaView>
          <Header />
          <Text>Hello I am the details screen</Text>
          <Pressable onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
            <Text>the icon</Text>
          </Pressable>
          <View>
            <Image source={item.image} />
          </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
      );
    };
    
    export default RecipeDetails;
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

Comment: Thank you that worked :)! I can now navigate to the page without an error, but my image doesn't render (I changed the "i" into a capital)

Comment: then do console the items and check the incoming data , if image object is present in it or not i.e. console.log(item,'the incoming items')

Comment: Thanks. I tried that. It still seems to not know what the "item" is ("item is undefined")

Comment: so the item is getting undefined data , please check the data you're sending to that item from the respective screen.